# How to get the original file name from "Uploadthing" in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using Uploadthing to upload my files and I wanted to show the name of my file. But the name in the response object of the uploadthing has its owm hashed name not he original name.

Original name: cov.pdf
res.name: b3391674-931b-422f-a966-fecdfabbb83a-245m.pdf

How can i get the original name.

**My code:**

```
<Form {...form}>
  <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="space-y-8">
    <div className="space-y-8 px-6">
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center text-center">
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="fileUrl"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormControl>
                <FileUpload
                  endpoint="messageFile"
                  value={field.value}
                  onChange={field.onChange}
                />
              </FormControl>
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
    <DialogFooter className="bg-gray-100 px-6 py-4">
      <Button variant={"primary"} disabled={isLoading}>
        Send
      </Button>
    </DialogFooter>
  </form>
</Form>;
```

```
<div className="relative flex items-center p-2 mt-2 rounded-md bg-background/10">
  <a href={value} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    <FileIcon className="h-10 w-10 fill-indigo-200 stroke-indigo-400" />
    <p>{value}</p>
  </a>
  <Button
    className="bg-rose-500 text-white p-1 rounded-full absolute top-0 right-0 shadow-sm h-4 w-4 hover:bg-red-500/70"
    type="button"
    onClick={() => onChange("")}
  >
    <X className="h-4 w-4" />
  </Button>
</div>;
```

I was expecting to get the original file name.